# Gem installation failure when deploying using Capistrano

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano

When trying to deploy a Rails application using Capistrano I receive this error:

```
An error occurred while installing mini_racer (0.6.2), and Bundler

cannot continue.

Make sure that `gem install mini_racer -v '0.6.2' --source

'https://rubygems.org/'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I have SSHed into the server and can install the gem without issue.
I have noticed that the server is running Ruby 2.6.3 and it seems like the gem might be trying to install in the wrong version.

```
Gem files will remain installed in

/home/deploy/apps/app-name/shared/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/mini_racer-0.6.2
```

Is there a way to manually install the gem?  Here's my Gemfile.lock for reference:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.1.4.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.1.4.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4.4)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.1.4.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.4)
      actionview (= 6.1.4.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.1.4.4)
      actionview (= 6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.9)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.1.4.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4.4)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    active_storage_validations (0.9.6)
      activejob (>= 5.2.0)
      activemodel (>= 5.2.0)
      activestorage (>= 5.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.2.0)
    activejob (6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
    activemodel-serializers-xml (1.0.2)
      activemodel (> 5.x)
      activesupport (> 5.x)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (6.1.4.4)
      activemodel (= 6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
    activerecord-postgis-adapter (7.1.1)
      activerecord (~> 6.1)
      rgeo-activerecord (~> 7.0.0)
    activestorage (6.1.4.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      marcel (~> 1.0.0)
      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
    activesupport (6.1.4.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
    addressable (2.8.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
    airbrussh (1.4.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.6.1, != 1.7.0)
    autoprefixer-rails (10.4.2.0)
      execjs (~> 2)
    azure-storage-blob (2.0.3)
      azure-storage-common (~> 2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1, >= 1.10.8)
    azure-storage-common (2.0.4)
      faraday (~> 1.0)
      faraday_middleware (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.0.rc1)
      net-http-persistent (~> 4.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1, >= 1.10.8)
    bcrypt (3.1.16)
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.10.3)
      msgpack (~> 1.2)
    bootstrap (4.3.1)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 9.1.0)
      popper_js (>= 1.14.3, < 2)
      sassc-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    bootstrap-datepicker-rails (1.9.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.0)
    bootstrap-select-rails (1.13.8)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    capistrano (3.16.0)
      airbrussh (>= 1.0.0)
      i18n
      rake (>= 10.0.0)
      sshkit (>= 1.9.0)
    capistrano-bundler (2.0.1)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
    capistrano-rails (1.6.1)
      capistrano (~> 3.1)
      capistrano-bundler (>= 1.1, < 3)
    capistrano-rvm (0.1.2)
      capistrano (~> 3.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.2)
    capistrano3-puma (4.0.0)
      capistrano (~> 3.7)
      capistrano-bundler
      puma (~> 4.0)
    capybara (3.36.0)
      addressable
      matrix
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (4.1.0)
    coderay (1.1.3)
    coffee-rails (5.0.0)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 5.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.12.2)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.9)
    connection_pool (2.2.5)
    crass (1.0.6)
    debase (0.2.4.1)
      debase-ruby_core_source (>= 0.10.2)
    debase-ruby_core_source (0.10.14)
    declarative (0.0.20)
    devise (4.8.1)
      bcrypt (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 4.1.0)
      responders
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    devise-security (0.17.0)
      devise (>= 4.3.0)
    elasticsearch (7.17.0)
      elasticsearch-api (= 7.17.0)
      elasticsearch-transport (= 7.17.0)
    elasticsearch-api (7.17.0)
      multi_json
    elasticsearch-model (7.2.0)
      activesupport (> 3)
      elasticsearch (~> 7)
      hashie
    elasticsearch-rails (7.2.0)
    elasticsearch-transport (7.17.0)
      faraday (~> 1)
      multi_json
    erubi (1.10.0)
    exception_notification (4.5.0)
      actionmailer (>= 5.2, < 8)
      activesupport (>= 5.2, < 8)
    excon (0.91.0)
    execjs (2.8.1)
    faraday (1.9.3)
      faraday-em_http (~> 1.0)
      faraday-em_synchrony (~> 1.0)
      faraday-excon (~> 1.1)
      faraday-httpclient (~> 1.0)
      faraday-multipart (~> 1.0)
      faraday-net_http (~> 1.0)
      faraday-net_http_persistent (~> 1.0)
      faraday-patron (~> 1.0)
      faraday-rack (~> 1.0)
      faraday-retry (~> 1.0)
      ruby2_keywords (>= 0.0.4)
    faraday-em_http (1.0.0)
    faraday-em_synchrony (1.0.0)
    faraday-excon (1.1.0)
    faraday-httpclient (1.0.1)
    faraday-multipart (1.0.3)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    faraday-net_http (1.0.1)
    faraday-net_http_persistent (1.2.0)
    faraday-patron (1.0.0)
    faraday-rack (1.0.0)
    faraday-retry (1.0.3)
    faraday_middleware (1.2.0)
      faraday (~> 1.0)
    ffi (1.15.5)
    font-awesome-rails (4.7.0.8)
      railties (>= 3.2, < 8.0)
    geocoder (1.7.3)
    gibbon (3.0.2)
      faraday (>= 0.9.1)
      multi_json (>= 1.11.0)
    globalid (1.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0)
    google-apis-core (0.4.2)
      addressable (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.1)
      googleauth (>= 0.16.2, < 2.a)
      httpclient (>= 2.8.1, < 3.a)
      mini_mime (~> 1.0)
      representable (~> 3.0)
      retriable (>= 2.0, < 4.a)
      rexml
      webrick
    google-apis-drive_v3 (0.18.0)
      google-apis-core (>= 0.4, < 2.a)
    googleauth (1.1.0)
      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 2.0)
      jwt (>= 1.4, < 3.0)
      memoist (~> 0.16)
      multi_json (~> 1.11)
      os (>= 0.9, < 2.0)
      signet (>= 0.16, < 2.a)
    haml (5.2.2)
      temple (>= 0.8.0)
      tilt
    hashie (5.0.0)
    httparty (0.20.0)
      mime-types (~> 3.0)
      multi_xml (>= 0.5.2)
    httpclient (2.8.3)
    hubspot-ruby (0.9.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
      httparty (>= 0.10.0)
    i18n (1.9.1)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    image_processing (1.12.1)
      mini_magick (>= 4.9.5, < 5)
      ruby-vips (>= 2.0.17, < 3)
    jbuilder (2.11.5)
      actionview (>= 5.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    jquery-rails (4.4.0)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (6.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.6)
    jwt (2.3.0)
    kaminari (1.2.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.1.0)
      kaminari-actionview (= 1.2.2)
      kaminari-activerecord (= 1.2.2)
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.2)
    kaminari-actionview (1.2.2)
      actionview
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.2)
    kaminari-activerecord (1.2.2)
      activerecord
      kaminari-core (= 1.2.2)
    kaminari-core (1.2.2)
    libv8-node (16.10.0.0)
    libv8-node (16.10.0.0-x86_64-linux)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.13.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    mail_form (1.9.0)
      actionmailer (>= 5.2)
      activemodel (>= 5.2)
    mandrill-api (1.0.55)
      excon (>= 0.16.0, < 1.0)
      json (>= 1.7.7, < 2.0)
    marcel (1.0.2)
    matrix (0.4.2)
    memoist (0.16.2)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mime-types (3.4.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2022.0105)
    mini_magick (4.11.0)
    mini_mime (1.1.2)
    mini_portile2 (2.7.1)
    mini_racer (0.6.2)
      libv8-node (~> 16.10.0.0)
    minitest (5.15.0)
    msgpack (1.4.4)
    multi_json (1.15.0)
    multi_xml (0.6.0)
    multipart-post (2.1.1)
    nested_form (0.3.2)
    net-http-persistent (4.0.1)
      connection_pool (~> 2.2)
    net-scp (3.0.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5, < 7.0.0)
    net-ssh (6.1.0)
    nio4r (2.5.8)
    nokogiri (1.13.1)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.7.0)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    nokogiri (1.13.1-x86_64-linux)
      racc (~> 1.4)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    os (1.1.4)
    pg (1.3.1)
    popper_js (1.16.0)
    pry (0.14.1)
      coderay (~> 1.1)
      method_source (~> 1.0)
    public_suffix (4.0.6)
    puma (4.3.10)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.6.0)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-pjax (1.1.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.5)
      rack (>= 1.1)
    rack-proxy (0.7.2)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.1.4.4)
      actioncable (= 6.1.4.4)
      actionmailbox (= 6.1.4.4)
      actionmailer (= 6.1.4.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.4)
      actiontext (= 6.1.4.4)
      actionview (= 6.1.4.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4.4)
      activemodel (= 6.1.4.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4.4)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 6.1.4.4)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-bootstrap-toggle-buttons (0.0.7)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.4.2)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    rails_admin (2.2.1)
      activemodel-serializers-xml (>= 1.0)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      haml (>= 4.0, < 6)
      jquery-rails (>= 3.0, < 5)
      jquery-ui-rails (>= 5.0, < 7)
      kaminari (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
      nested_form (~> 0.3)
      rack-pjax (>= 0.7)
      rails (>= 5.0, < 7)
      remotipart (~> 1.3)
      sassc-rails (>= 1.3, < 3)
    rails_admin_actiontext (0.0.3)
      rails (>= 5.2.0, < 7)
      rails_admin (>= 1.0)
    rails_email_validator (0.1.4)
      activemodel (>= 3.0.0)
    railties (6.1.4.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4.4)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.13)
      thor (~> 1.0)
    rake (13.0.6)
    rb-fsevent (0.11.1)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    recaptcha (5.8.1)
      json
    regexp_parser (2.2.0)
    remotipart (1.4.4)
    representable (3.1.1)
      declarative (< 0.1.0)
      trailblazer-option (>= 0.1.1, < 0.2.0)
      uber (< 0.2.0)
    responders (3.0.1)
      actionpack (>= 5.0)
      railties (>= 5.0)
    retriable (3.1.2)
    rexml (3.2.5)
    rgeo (2.4.0)
    rgeo-activerecord (7.0.1)
      activerecord (>= 5.0)
      rgeo (>= 1.0.0)
    ruby-debug-ide (0.7.3)
      rake (>= 0.8.1)
    ruby-vips (2.1.4)
      ffi (~> 1.12)
    ruby2_keywords (0.0.5)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    rubyzip (2.3.2)
    sass (3.7.4)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.1.0)
      railties (>= 5.2.0)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    sassc (2.4.0)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    selenium-webdriver (4.1.0)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 5.0)
      rexml (~> 3.2, >= 3.2.5)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    signet (0.16.0)
      addressable (~> 2.8)
      faraday (>= 0.17.3, < 2.0)
      jwt (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.10)
    sitemap_generator (6.2.1)
      builder (~> 3.0)
    social-share-button (1.2.4)
      coffee-rails
    spring (2.1.1)
    spring-watcher-listen (2.0.1)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      spring (>= 1.2, < 3.0)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.4.2)
      actionpack (>= 5.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sshkit (1.21.2)
      net-scp (>= 1.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.8.0)
    sshkit-sudo (0.1.0)
      sshkit (~> 1.8)
    stripe (5.43.0)
    stripe_event (2.3.1)
      activesupport (>= 3.1)
      stripe (>= 2.8, < 6)
    temple (0.8.2)
    thor (1.2.1)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    trailblazer-option (0.1.2)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    uber (0.1.0)
    warden (1.2.9)
      rack (>= 2.0.9)
    web-console (4.2.0)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (5.0.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (~> 4.0)
    webpacker (4.3.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 4.2)
    webrick (1.7.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    wepay (0.4.0)
    wicked (1.4.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.7)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
    zeitwerk (2.5.4)

PLATFORMS
  ruby
  x86_64-linux

DEPENDENCIES
  active_storage_validations
  activerecord-postgis-adapter
  azure-storage-blob
  bootsnap (>= 1.4.2)
  bootstrap (~> 4.3.1)
  bootstrap-datepicker-rails
  bootstrap-select-rails
  byebug
  capistrano (< 5)
  capistrano-bundler
  capistrano-rails
  capistrano-rvm
  capistrano3-puma (< 5)
  capybara (>= 2.15)
  debase
  devise
  devise-security
  elasticsearch-model (~> 7)
  elasticsearch-rails (~> 7)
  exception_notification
  font-awesome-rails
  geocoder
  gibbon (~> 3.0.0)
  google-apis-drive_v3
  hubspot-ruby
  image_processing (~> 1.2)
  jbuilder (~> 2.5)
  jquery-rails
  listen (>= 3.0.5, < 3.2)
  mail_form
  mandrill-api
  mini_racer
  pg
  pry
  puma (< 5)
  rails (~> 6.0)
  rails-bootstrap-toggle-buttons
  rails_admin (~> 2.0)
  rails_admin_actiontext
  rails_email_validator
  recaptcha
  ruby-debug-ide
  sass-rails (~> 5)
  sassc (~> 2.3)
  selenium-webdriver
  sitemap_generator
  social-share-button
  spring
  spring-watcher-listen (~> 2.0.0)
  sshkit-sudo
  stripe
  stripe_event
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  web-console (>= 3.3.0)
  webdrivers
  webpacker (~> 4.0)
  wepay (~> 0.4.0)
  wicked

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.6.3p62

BUNDLED WITH
   1.17.2
```

Comment: Please see this thread for answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52264369/error-occurred-while-installing-mini-racer-0-2-0

Answer (score 0):

Also, install mini_racer to version '0.2.15', it will fetch libv8 & hopefully solve the issue